# How to take Storybook's Storyshots after Vue's nextTick?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, storybook, storyshots

I'm using Storybook's Storyshots with Vue and loving it, but now I've created some custom directives that alter the DOM on `$nextTick`, I'd like to be able to wait and take the storyshots after `$nextTick` so the DOM is represented properly.

Can anyone help explain how I might achieve this?

My setup is:

```
initStoryshots({
  configPath: 'src/_storybook',
  suite: 'web-apps',
  test: multiSnapshotWithOptions(),
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For doing that you'll need to configure Jest to make async tests mounting yourself the stories. It sound's harder that it is actually. This is my configuration on storybook.spec.js

```
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

initStoryshots({
  asyncJest: true,
  async test({ story, done }) {
    const wrapper = mount(story.render());

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
    done();
  }
});
```